# Múltiplas respostas

Tags: debate

Sempre que pesquiso uma pergunta no Stack Overflow em inglês, percebo que existem várias respostas para a mesma pergunta, muitas vezes com pequenas variações e detalhes diferentes de implementação. Já no SOpt percebo que é diferente, normalmente temos respostas canônicas e poucas ou nenhuma resposta complementar.

Isso ocorre por alguma diretriz da comunidade em português ou é algo que emergiu naturalmente pelo perfil de uso dos brasileiros?

Comment: Depende muito. O site não é acessado só por brasileiros, tem que levar em consideração pessoas de outros países com idioma português. E existe muitas perguntas com apenas uma resposta. Acho que um dos principais motivos seja marca a resposta como aceita muito rápido. Quando eu faço uma pergunta eu espero no minimo 24h para marcar uma resposta como aceita, acho que dessa forma motiva mais quem for responder, dá mais tempo.

Comment: Opa, Sou usuário Angolano e o stack Português me ajuda muito.
concordo plenamente com o @marcell

Comment: Concordo com o @gato eu deixo pelo menos 2 dias, mas a maioria das vezes 5 dias pelo menos. Para que possam aparecer mais repostas, nunca se sabe o que pode aparecer de interessante. E não quero desmotivar ninguém de responder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O **SOen** (inglês) existe desde o final de 2008, a cultura lá veio evoluindo de maneiras diferentes, passou por alguns períodos diferentes, o **SOpt** começou mais "pensado", com um grupo de participantes que já tinham experiencia e até pensavam em um ideal semelhante, fora que o publico de que fala português é muito menor.

> **Nota:** não somos uma comunidade de brasileiros, somo uma comunidade que usa o idioma português, ou seja temos usuários principalmente Portugueses e Brasileiros e podemos também ter usuários de:
>
> - São Tomé e Príncipe
> - Angola
> - Moçambique
> - Cabo Verde
> - Timor Leste
> - Guiné-Bissau
> - Guiné Equatorial
>
> https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/148/8

No **SOen** participam várias, pessoas nativas de inglês ou não (claro que tem por obrigação que escrever em inglês para tornar o conteúdo acessível para qualquer visitante, ou para a maioria), lá se notar existem muitos participantes com ideias variadas, uma coisa que existe no **SOen** e nem todo mundo gosta é a tipica resposta:

> Try this
>
> ```
> Answer code
> ```

Nem todos gostam deste tipo de resposta sem orientação, mas é difícil controlar isto lá, aqui no SOpt as vezes temos o:

> Tente isto
>
> ```
> Código da resposta
> ```

Mas pelo publico ser menor e a cultura desde o começo formada pela comunidade (pessoas que participam mais ativamente) que o minimo ideal é que as respostas abordem o assunto todo mostrando os melhores caminhos e citando possiveis problemas que poderá enfrentar.

No **SOpt** as vezes aparecem respostas que são apenas links, pela comunidade ser um pouco mais fácil de qualificar o conteúdo essas respostas são removidas geralmente, nesse meio tempo notará que aparecem respostas alternativas algumas vezes, no SOen o pessoal também incentiva a não apenar mostrar links, como no próprio Help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer:

> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

mas já notei usuário veteranos com alta reputação respondendo apenas com links, isto foi recente, ou seja é uma questão de atitude da comunidade e varia o quanto essa comunidade interage entre si (conversam, trocam ideias, se preocupam com a qualidade do conteúdo), no **SOen** tem muitas pessoas preocupadas sim com isto, inclusive conheci um usuário veterano que entrou em muitos conflitos com outros usuário veteranos, ele foi banido por motivos que desconheço e não vou ficar citando o caso aqui, mas ele realmente se preocupava com conteúdo das respostas.

### Concluindo

No SOpt:

- Por ser uma comunidade menor as pessoas tem maior facilidade de interagir
- O mais veteranos tentam orientar os novatos
- Muitos já tiveram experiencias no SOen e tentaram trazer coisas que gostam de lá e evitar coisas que desgostam
- Por falarmos todos um mesmo idioma (raramente alguém que não seja nativo português ou bilíngue irá participar do SOpt) as orientações e ideias fluem melhor (no SOen muitos usam ferramentas de tradução)

Devido aos itens anteriores então temos uma "cultura" de tentar na primeira resposta detalhar todos pontos possíveis ou que conhecemos, por exemplo o usuário vem como uma pergunta assim:

- [Erro ao executar o mysql_query](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151609/3635)

Note que o usuário Bacco além de responder ele ainda explica que o uso da API mysql no PHP está obsoleto e deve ser trocado pela API mysqli para poder usar banco mySql, ou seja ele foi além de resolver o problema do autor da pergunta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151610/3635

Então por este motivo raramente você verá múltiplas respostas, porque se uma resposta já toca em todos pontos de um problema então não há tanta necessidade de múltiplas respostas, a não ser que realmente venha trazendo alguma informação nova.

### Uma nota pessoal

Infelizmente ainda passamos e sempre passaremos por uma coisa muito ruim, algumas pessoas pensam que somos site de *"suporte técnico"*, tipo resolva o meu código, as vezes uma pessoa responde explicando várias falhas no código ou apontando problemas por algo ser obsoleto e até tenta mostrar um melhor caminho codificando um exemplo, mas o autor da pergunta retruca falando que só quer resolver o problema especifico e isto não ocorre só com o autor, alguns participantes também tem a visão de que somos um tipo de **suporte técnico**.

Não estou querendo dizer que não estamos aqui para ajudar, mas a ideia é que a pergunta do autor deve servir para futuros visitantes também, se for para remendar um código cheio de problemas fazendo uma gambiarra, ou dar uma resposta com códigos obsoletos então nem a pergunta e nem a resposta servirão para futuros visitantes, somo um Q&A e não um "sistema de tickets" para resolver um problema e aquilo não servir para mais ninguém.

Muitas pessoas consultam o site e resolvem seus problemas sem precisar perguntar, graças as perguntas e respostas existentes, se fossemos ficar só no assistencialismo respondendo com remendos ou sem entoar outros possíveis problemas (além de códigos obsoletos) pode ter certeza que uma pergunta teria facilmente mais de 5 respostas.

Answer (score 8):

A minha teoria é que existe um abismo de conhecimento. De um lado, pessoas que sãos mestres no que fazem, de outro, crianças (*script kids*).

Se isso for verdade, existem 4 interações:

1. de **mestre** para **mestre**

Aonde meia palavra basta. Apenas um "tente isto" já é suficiente. Pois ele é certeiro, com precisão cirúrgica. Ambas as partes dominam o assunto, e não é preciso explicar todos os detalhes, apenas os detalhes que importam.

2. de **mestre** para **criança**

Aonde o mestre precisa segurar a mão da criança a cada passo da caminhada. Se não a criança esperneia, e diz que o mestre não sabe o que está fazendo. Como um bebê recém nascido, muitas vezes a criança nem sabe expressar qual é o problema dela.

3. de **criança** para **mestre**

Aonde um "tente isto" não faz o menor sentido. Uma resposta que parece ser (ou é) um clássico <kbd>control</kbd> +<kbd>c</kbd> com <kbd>control</kbd> +<kbd>v</kbd>. Normalmente a criança irá sofrer dolorosamente por isso.

4. de **criança** para **criança**

Aonde não se espera nada, mas que de vez em quando funciona. Não me pergunte como, só sei que funciona. Crianças brigam por qualquer coisa, são a "alegria" dos moderadores (alegria é sarcasmo neste caso).

- Existe também a questão de **esforço**.

Não espere uma resposta **bem** feita, para uma pergunta **mal** feita. Sério, você tenta responder da melhor maneira. Mas é como se as pessoas parassem apenas para rir da sua cara e dizer: Ha Ha, bem-feito!

- Existe a questão da **complexidade**

Não existe razão para explicar algo avançado, se a pessoa não entende nem a parte básica. Como aconteceu em [O que é CQRS e como implementar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181688/64). Desculpe, mas não vou escrever um livro pra você. Espere algum mestre ter misericórdia e escrever um mini livro pra você. O que quase aconteceu naquele exemplo ali, mas na verdade não respondeu o que realmente precisava ser respondido.

- Existe a questão de saber se a **pessoa que está perguntando** sabe **o que está perguntado**

Por exemplo, novamente o caso de [O que é CQRS e como implementar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181688/64) Não sabe qual o motivo de existir CQRS e em que situações ele deve ser usado, mas quer saber como implementar. Essa é uma pegadinha, pois na maioria das vezes, você só sabe que a pessoa não sabe o que perguntou, depois que já respondeu. Dependendo do que for, você vai receber vários downvotes. Pois parece que você quer resolver o problema que a pessoa não tem. Mas na verdade você quer resolver o problema que a pessoa têm, mas ela ainda não sabe que tem. O downvote é devido as crianças não acreditarem em você, a não ser que vocẽ escreva tudo nos mínimos detalhes, do começo ao fim, com observações do autor e dedicatória. As vezes parece preguiça de ler a documentação ou algo do tipo.

- Existe a questão de **fazer a coisa certa**

Por exemplo, quando alguém pega um livro antigo de Java sobre calendários (do jeito que era usado 15 anos atrás), e alguém pergunta o jeito certo de usar aquilo. A pessoa que sabe o certo, vai dizer pra usar `java.time` em vez daquela porcaria antiga. Ela precisa explicar bem explicado, pois é praticamente reescrever boa parte do código. Ou seja, é o "pega tudo e joga fora" que pode facilmente acabar como "eu sei tudo, vocẽ não sabe nada, cai fora". Infelizmente ainda tem muita velharia sendo ensinada pras crianças.

- Existe a questão de **roubar as respostas dos outros**

Responder com algo semelhante causa briga. Quase [aconteceu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961099/using-regex-in-hg-revset/42982651#42982651) isso comigo no Stack internacional nesses dias. Minha resposta é quase que 100% igual ao do oponente, mas eu testei na minha máquina, e ela resolve o problema. O oponente modificou a resposta dele depois de ver a minha. Enfim, se algum colega acreditar que vocẽ está roubando dele, é briga na certa. Seja honesto, se você utilizou algo de alguém, pelo menos cite o nome do autor.

**RESUMINDO**

Analisando as vantagens e desvantagens:

**Ou você responde bem respondido, ou corre o risco de ser apedrejado**.

Pelo menos não será crucificado, penso eu. ;D

**OBS**

1-Mestre e criança são  apenas uma figura de linguagem. Se você realmente é uma criança, não fique chateado, todo adulto já foi uma criança um dia.

2-Se eu me considero mestre ou criança? Eu sou mais uma criança velha que parece mestre. Ou um mestre que parece uma criança velha.

3-"Tente isto:" da [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5896/64) de Edison de Brito foi a inspiração principal do meu texto.

4-Sei que essa questão parece estar decidida. Mas considero interessante publicar um ponto de vista adicional.

Comment: Essa é uma das melhores respostas do meta. Concordo plenamente. Adiciono que a criança sempre acha que  está mais próxima de ser mestre  do que realmente é, afinal ela nem entende a realidade que vive. Na verdade o adolescente é até mais problemático aqui, todo mundo reconhece a criança e trata diferente, o adolescente é pior tratar diferente e nada fará ele mudar de ideia a não ser a chegada da maturidade, se chegar um dia. A resposta do Edilson Brito sequer faz algum sentido. Fui verificar e não achei o que ele afirma ter acontecido, parece um caso de recém nascido.

Answer (score -6):

Já respondi com o famigerado

Tente isto:

```
Código exemplo
```

E fui apedrejado por um "moderador" isso sim somente serve para desmotivar a contribuir com SOpt.
Muitas vezes pelo pouco tempo disponível é o melhor que pode ser feito, e um pequeno trecho de código pode ser o start necessário para sanar a duvida do solicitante.

Comment: Seria bom mostrar onde isto aconteceu pra gente analisar.

Comment: prontos, agora foi apedrejado novamente. Tenta ao menos entrar no contexto, e se achar que não possui o suficiente para colaborar com uma resposta, um comentário é suficiente. O problema é que algumas pessoas às vezes só respondem para ganhar pontos, por isso acabam por falar de coisas que desconhecem na maior parte das vezes , *pesquisar, entender, resumir* e no final se achar que já é capaz de responder, à vontade, caso contrário, opa, você perdeu tempo, mas aprendeu algo novo.

Comment: @Edilson ninguém está a apedrejar ninguém. O bigown só queria saber onde aconteceu isso para lhe poder ajudar.

Comment: @JorgeB. falo mesmo dos downvotes, que só parecem estar a aumentar.

Comment: @Edilson os downvotes no meta só servem pra mostrar que concorda ou discorda de si. Não são nenhum ataque pessoal. É só a forma de dizer "eu concordo" ou "eu discordo" do que você disse.

Comment: @JorgeB. talvez faça menos sentido o meu *foi apedrejado novamente* assim dito, me refiro a resposta dele, onde ele diz que foi *apedrejado (em palavras dele)* devido a uma resposta, sendo que ele respondeu agora com outra vez com uma resposta algo fora do contexto e recebeu novamente downvotes.