# Essa pergunta é válida para o site?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Analisando a pergunta abaixo, me pergunto se a mesma é válida para o site:

[Visual Studio 2015 - Alto consumo de RAM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195184/20615)

A pergunta em si, pergunta se **o consumo de memória está normal**, mas no contexto (corpo da pergunta) o AP comenta que isso está causando uma grande lentidão no computador.

O consumo apresentado pelo Visual Studio, é baixo se realmente for ver, todavia, existem alguns fatores que podem provocar a lentidão, como por exemplo:

- Configuração do Computador
- Estado do SO do computador
- Extensões instaladas no VS
- Processos executando ao mesmo tempo (IISExpress, VSHub, browser, etc)
- Projeto a ser trabalhado

Como podemos ver no [no comentário do @jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195184/visual-studio-2015-alto-consumo-de-ram#comment402186_195184), o consumo de um projeto dele foi muito diferente:

> Não tá normal mesmo, tá muito baixo. Fique feliz! Eu abri um projeto pra debuggar e tá em 1200MB. – jbueno

Tendo em vista que em muitos casos o consumo é superior ao mostrado na pergunta, não estaria normal. Mas, também pode estar, visto que um projeto novo também pode chegar a um valor próximo, [como mostrado na resposta do @artur-o-templário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195187/20615).

E também temos [a resposta do @bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195185/20615), onde ele tentou ser o mais objetivo e imparcial possível. Porém, como eu disse acima, não tem como falar com exatidão o motivo da lentidão do computador, as vezes pode ser somente falta de memória...

Com isso, vem a minha dúvida:

Essa pergunta é válida para o escopo do site? Se não, qual seria o motivo de fechamento mais adequado?

Comment: Lendo a pergunta do AP me parece que o problema não esta relacionado diretamente com VS, provavelmente é outro processo que esta consumindo a memoria, algo relacionado ao VS (acredito que não :P) ou ao sistema. Se for isso, não tem como identificar quem é o "processo vilão" da RAM, o AP precisaria editar a pergunta e fornecer mais detalhe a respeito do ambiente dele e do que pode ser a causa do alto consumo de memoria. Então esta pergunta poderia sim ser fechada como "não clara", mas não por ser uma pergunta invalida.

Answer (score 8):

> O Stack Overflow é voltado para programadores profissionais e estudantes, pessoas que escrevem programas por amor. Acreditamos que as melhores perguntas no Stack Overflow têm sempre um pouco de código, mas se a sua pergunta tem a ver com...
>
> - um problema específico de programação
> - um algorítmo de software
> - **ferramentas comuns entre programadores**
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
> - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software
>
> … então este é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta

O que é o Visual Studio?

A pergunta não tem nada de hardware, é sobre o Visual Studio, uma ferramenta comum entre programadores.

A pergunta tem um foco, está clara, pode ser respondida objetivamente, é uma dúvida pertinente de quem não sabe se aquilo é correto ou não e precisa de uma resposta de alguém mais experiente. A pergunta pode parecer boba, parece uma [pergunta de criança](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5903/101), mas é uma pergunta válida e que provavelmente muita gente tem.

Programação não é só linha de código. Talvez por acharem isso é que deve ter tanto programador que só vão até a página 3.

O fechamento existe para evitar perguntas inúteis, que não ajudam ninguém da audiência do site. O fechamento não existe por si próprio. Ele existe para resolver problemas. Que problema esta pergunta causa? Vamos nos concentrar nas que não agregam valor algum ao site. Essa é simples, é coisa básica, mas pode ser objetiva e útil para quem não sabe.

Comment: A pergunta não fala de nada sobre o VS e sim do consumo de memória. Assim como a sua resposta não responde a pergunta e sim fala para ele uma configuração excelente para resolver o problema dele.
Lendo a resposta atentamente, assim como coloquei em minha pergunta, mostra que ele está falando da lentidão do computador e usou a memória consumida pelo VS como problema.

Comment: Indo um pouco mais além, sua resposta induziu (diretamente ou indiretamente) [a compra de memória pelo AP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195184/visual-studio-2015-alto-consumo-de-ram/195187#comment402192_195185), o que pode não servir de nada para resolver a lentidão do problema, caso a configuração do computador não seja boa, ou caso ele possua algo a mais no computado que não **conseguimos saber** causando a lentidão do mesmo.

Comment: Como não fala de VS? O consumo de memória é do que então? Perunta: "Este consumo está normal?". Resposta: "Só isso? Eu diria que é pouco. Visual Studio, como todos os IDEs poderosos são devoradores de memória, provavelmente não há aplicação desktop que use tanta memória". E como resolver o problema da lentidão: "Para usar bem recomendo 16GB de RAM e um bom SSD". Também falei que extensões podem causar lentidão. Respondi o que dava. Se a pergunta tivesse mais informações eu poderia responder mais. Mas ao que foi perguntado foi respondido.

Comment: Ele mostra parte dos processos e o VS sozinho consome menos do que tudo que ele executa junto. Então, a pergunta não fala diretamente sobre o VS.
Pode ter algo consumindo 50% da memória nesta foto, o que está causando a lentidão, o que não tem como saber.
Ele pode colocar os 16GB de memória e o SSD, mas e o windows estiver com problemas e/ou o processador não for bom, pode continuar lento da mesma forma.

Comment: Note também que eu não perguntei se ela faz parte do escopo, e sim se ela é válida no site. Na pergunta eu pergunto qual o melhor motivo de fechamento caso ela **não seja válida**.

Comment: Você pode dizer que a pergunta não está clara, mas não que ela não é válida para o site. "Essa pergunta é válida para o escopo do site?" então perguntou se é válida para o escopo do site. Se alguém achar que não está clara, pode votar assim, o AP achou que respondeu. Se problema for outro ele não disse, só podemos falar sobre o que ele posta, o que ele não posta fica difícil adivinhar. A pergunta pode não ser uma maravilha, você pode não gostar da resposta, mas ela é válida. É possível perguntar pra ele alguma coisa que não tenha ficado claro.

Comment: A palavra "escopo" pode ter sido um equívoco meu, não era bem isso que eu queria dizer. Todavia, por se tratar de windows, o computador pode estar lento mesmo sem o VS. Apenas removendo os vírus ou formatando pode resolver.
A pessoa pode ter 8GB de memória que dá para trabalhar muito bem, e agora irá comprar outro para ter 16GB.
Outra pessoa que ler a pergunta pode não saber o que foi perguntado realmente, e pensar que 6GB é pouco, o que não é.
Por esse e outros fatores, eu acho que a pergunta possui alguns problemas, e que não se encaixa no site.

Comment: Ressalto também que não tenho nada contra a resposta, pelo contrário, acho a configuração que você indicou perfeita para trabalhar. Só acho que a pergunta pode causar problemas para outras pessoas que a lerem, e colocar mais memória **no caso do AP**, pode não resolver o problema dele.

Comment: Eu disse que ela tem problemas. Isso pode ser comentado lá. Eu melhorei a resposta.

Comment: Gostei da forma que disse que pode ter outros fatores. Como eu disse em minha pergunta, achei sua resposta objetiva e imparcial. Todavia, ainda acho que esse tipo de pergunta pode ter causar mais problemas do que benefícios.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o SOPT é um Q&A de perguntas relacionadas a **programação**... é um escopo bem especifico...java, php(há controversias), c#,c,haskell... a partir do momento que foge do termo programação... entra em questão fisica (hardware) já sai do escopo do site e explico os motivos disso:

- Ficaria assuntos diversos relacionados a uma mesma tag... por
  exemplo no android-studio , que consome muita memória, haveria
  perguntas do tipo, "quero reduzir o consumo de memória do android
  studio", além de estar muito mal formulada nada acrescenta valores
  relacionados a programação.
- se permitir esse tipo de    pergunta teremos que permitir sobre
  outros assuntos também... É bem    obvio a partir do momento que uma
  pergunta do tipo entrar no site    outras também entrarão por
  inércia...
- nenhum dos outros tipos de SO ligados a programação aceita
  perguntas de hardware... não é uma regra nossa mas é quase como um
  padrão geral.

**Opinião pessoal:**
Sou contra perguntas não relacionadas a programação... mas sei que existe exceções,"muitas imagens estouram a memória da aplicação", é diferente de  "Meu IDE explode a memória só de ligar", e se abrir um site sobre hardware eu sou completamente a favor, é um assunto que gosto muito e que adoraria que houvesse um em pt.

Comment: Concordo com você, tirando a parte que apenas o que colocou como escopo ficou muito "pequeno". Todavia, penso da mesma forma.